# What is SecurityDescriptor format?

Tags: bcs, security-trimming

[MSDN article "How to: Configure item-level security in SharePoint 2013"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg294169.aspx) mentions service returning Property with `Name="WindowsSecurityDescriptorField"`. What is actual format, in which this information should be returned?

If there are many users/AD groups that have permissions to read the data - how are the users list returned? (eg.: domain\login, od SIDs, or else? how are they delimited?)

I want to crawl external data from OData service and I need security information, so that the index has security trimming info, but I don't know how it is implemented.

Comment: This is described on a StackOverflow thread. [Implementing Security on custom BCS/.net class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596534/implementing-security-on-custom-bcs-net-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That field is the name of a property of your entity, which returns a byte-encoded (byte[]) representation of the encoded claims.

Here's a great example: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/security_trimming_in_sharepoint_2013/2012/10/29/creating-custom-connector-sending-claims-with-sharepoint-2013/

Format as quoted from above link:
The encoding is done according to the protocol documentation where:

> - The first byte signals an allow or deny claim
> - The second byte is always 1 to indicate that this is a non-NT security ACL (i.e. it is a claim ACL type)
> - The next four bytes is the size of the following claim value array.
> - The claim value string follows as a Unicode byte array.
>     – The next four bytes following the claim value array, gives the length of the claim type
> - The claim type string follows as a Unicode byte array.
>     – The next four bytes following the claim type array, gives the length of the claim data type
> - The claim data type string follows as a Unicode byte array
> - The next four bytes following the claim data type array, gives the length of the claim original issuer
> - The claim issuer string finally follows as a Unicode byte array